# How to raise a 410 error in Django

Tags: python, django, error-handling, httpresponse, http-status-code-410

I'd like to return 410 errors at for some of my Django pages instead of returning 404s. Basically, instead of calling `raise Http404('some error message')`, I would like to instead call `raise Http410('some error message')` shortcut.

I am confused because in django.http, the function Http404 is simply:

```
class Http404(Exception):
    pass
```

So if I do the same thing and create my Http410 function, I would assume it would look like:

```
class Http410(Exception):
    pass
```

However, doing this returns the exception but serves up a 500 error page. How do I recreate the magic of the Http404 exception? I should note, I need to raise the exception from my models (not views) so I can't just return an HttpResponseGone.

Thanks in advance!

Update:
I am fully aware of HttpResponseGone and mentioned this in my original question. I already know how to return this in my views. My question is: How do you raise an Http 410 exception similarly to how you raise an Http 404 exception? I want to be able to raise this exception anywhere, not just in my views. Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Django does not include a mechanism for this because gone should be normal workflow, not an error condition, but if you want to not treat it as a return response, and as an exception, just implement a [middleware](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/).

```
class MyGoneMiddleware(object):
    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        if isinstance(exception, Http410):
            return HttpResponseGone("Gone!")
        return None
```

Comment: @Spike Any reason why you can't just return a `HttpResponseGone` object instead of raising an exception and having the middleware inject the object, instead?

Comment: I decided to just return a HttpResponseGone object since that seems to be the normal way to do things. I am keeping your answer marked as answered, though, because you answered the exact question I originally asked.

Comment: @Santa It would be nice to raise instead of return because sometimes you need to do it from within a deeply nested function call, far away from your view function.

Answer (score 24):

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
return HttpResponse(status=410)
```

Answer (score 11):

Return a `HttpResponseGone`, a subclass of [`HttpResponse`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse), in your view handler.